# How to set barTintColor from the UINavigationBar subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a subclass of the `UINavigationBar`.
How can I set `barTintColor` in this subclass?

```
class NavBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 66)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override the initialisers of `UINavigationBar`.

```
class NavBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        // Change barTintColor to whatever you would like 
        self.barTintColor = .red
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 66)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work by subclassing `UINavigationController` and setting `barTintColor` from there:

```
class NavBarVC: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.someColor
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: In the end I used solution from the @dirtydanee's answer. Thus I don't need to subclass `UINavigationController`.